# How to get the github repository release version in react

Tags: reactjs, github, repository, version

I don't see an answer to my question online so i'll just ask there :)

Let's say you release v1.0.1 of your website on your github repo, how can it be displayed on the website (ReactJS in my case) ? Is this even possible ?

And obviously I would like it to be updated as I push new updates.

Thanks for reading !!!

Comment: Where is "v1.0.1" defined? Is that a Git tag, or versioning in your `package.json`, or something else?

Comment: Yeah it's a git tag but tell me if you know how to get the versioning in the package.json too :)

Comment: I think I'd add it an an env variable to my start and build scripts. Something like this: https://dev.to/nastassia/add-commit-hash-version-to-your-react-app-n3n

Comment: Yeah i found that `REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version`is working in local but it's apparently not possible to deploy like that, I added the env variable by hand (Vercel).